# Ruby on Rails 3 how to display information from the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeview

I have a database and I want to select data from it by pressing a button.
Run  $ rails c

```
1.9.2p290 :001 >Book.find_by_price("50")
# => #<Book id: 1, price: "50"><Book id: 2, price: "50"><Book id: 3, price: "50">
```

In the console, he finds the right information, but how to show it in the view?
I tried to write a method in the controller.

```
books_controller.rb
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @books = Book.all
    @metod = Book.find_by_price("50")
  end
 #...
end
```

And then, in the view

```
view/books/index.html.erb
<%= link_to @metod %>
```

But it does not work. Please tell me how is it done?
I would want that these data are displayed when I click the button in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the dynamic finders of ActiveRecord, `find_by_price` should return a single record.  But in the console output, it is returning an array so I'm assuming that you manually created that method in your Book model.  If the intended output is to list all books with a price of 50, use the following code in your view.

```
<% @metod.each do |book| %>
  <%= link_to book, book %>
<% end %>
```

This code loops through each book in `@metod` and displays a link that goes to the `show` action of its corresponding controller.

Comment: hmm, i tot find_by is just returning one record whereas find_all_by only return array ?

Comment: that's correct. but in the question, `find_by_price` returns an array (as seen in the console snippet). which is why i have the explanation in my answer.

Comment: thx, this work! I made a mistake and changed find_by_price("50") on where(:price => "50") how can I make a call to button that result?

Answer (score 1):

you can use a loop to get all the value from @books

```
@books.each do |book|
  <%= book.name %>
  <%= book.price %>
end
```

doing

```
@metod = Book.find_by_price("50")
```

@metod is an instance variable, to access it, you can do @metod.price

Comment: what you described activerecord creates automatically, for example, I have nine books in a database with different prices, I want to make a button which when pressed will show only three of the nine entries

Comment: erm, maybe you can link_to a path and pass param, In the index, you can check , if param[:something].blank? something else  @metod = Book.find_by_price("50")

Comment: thx, maybe, but I want the result appear only when I click a button, and not permanently